# Hagan's implied vol formula for Normal SABR

Tags: sabr

I'm sure there's an obvious answer to this question so apologies. But reading through [this](https://web.math.ku.dk/%7Erolf/SABR.pdf) seminal paper on the SABR model, the author's provide an explicit formula for the (normal) implied vol of a $\tau$-expiry, strike $K$ option, $\sigma_N(K)$ (ibid. equations A67a,b). For the case $\beta=0$ (i.e. for a Bachelier distribution of the forward $f$) this formula simplifies to
\begin{equation}
\sigma_N(K)=\alpha\frac{\zeta}{D(\zeta)}\left(1+\frac{2-3\rho^2}{24}\nu^2\tau\right)\tag{1} 
\end{equation}
where $\alpha,\nu,\rho$ are the remaining SABR parameters, \begin{equation}\zeta=\frac{\nu}{\alpha}(f-K) \tag{2}\end{equation} and \begin{equation}D(\zeta)=\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-2\rho\zeta+\zeta^2}-\rho+\zeta}{1-\rho}\right).\end{equation} Now, the authors "further simplify" $(1)$ by recasting $\zeta$  (through a series expansion of the term $(f-K)$) as \begin{equation}\zeta=\frac{\nu}{\alpha}\sqrt{fK}\ln\left(\frac{f}{K}\right)\tag{3}\end{equation} with $D(\zeta)$ as before (ibid. equations A69a,b). It escapes me as to exactly why this is done: is it purely to eliminate $K$ and $f$ having opposite signs and setting $K \in (0,\infty]$? Not only does taking $\zeta$ as given by $(2)$ allow for smile calibration to negative strikes, taking it in the form $(3)$ (implemented on a computer) gives poor fitting for deep OTM strikes and nasty behavior for strikes close to zero.

Comment: I believe the main reason for doing this is the ATM case when K=F. You then get expressions like 0/0 in the unmodified formula and also probably issues with numerical cancellation when F is close to K.

Comment: Thanks. But you still have 0/0 for $\zeta/D(\zeta)$ for $f=K$ even with $\zeta$ taken as (3). In production SABR I believe the ATM case is dealt with by doing a Taylor expansion of $D(\zeta)$ when $|f-K|$ is small, so that $\lim_{f\to K}(\zeta/D(\zeta)) =1 $, but this works for $\zeta$ given by either (2) or (3).